# Updatea dataframe with another one on matching rows like SQL update with a join statement

Tags: r, sql-update, match

Is there any simple way to update a subset of dataframe rows using another one?

Practically, I want to use `R` to do `UPDATE x INNER JOIN y ON x.col1 = y.col1 SET x.col2 = y.col2`

## Inputs:

```
x <- data.frame(col1=c('a','c','b','d'), col2=c(11,34,13,25))
```

[image]

```
y <- data.frame(col1=c('a','b'), col2=c(3,5))
```

[image]

```
z <- match(x$col1,y$col1)
```

> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFBAU.png)  1 NA  2 NA

## Outputs:

**Method 1**

```
x$col2 <- y$col2[z]
```

[image]

**Method 2**

```
x$col2[z] <- y$col2[z]
```

> Error in x$col2[z] <- y$col2[z] :    NAs are not allowed in
>   subscripted assignments

**Method 3**

```
x$col2[z[!is.na(z)]] <- y$col2[z[!is.na(z)]]
```

[image]

## Desired Output:

in `x` update only the values that match in `col1` of `y`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `match` in base R:

```
x$col2[match(y$col1, x$col1)] <- y$col2
x

#  col1 col2
#1    a    3
#2    c   34
#3    b    5
#4    d   25
```

Or `left_join` and `coalesce` in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

left_join(x, y, by = 'col1') %>%
  mutate(col2 = coalesce(col2.y, col2.x)) %>%
  select(names(x))
```

---

Most efficient would be an update join in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)

setDT(x)
setDT(y)
x[y, on=.(col1), col2:=i.col2]
```

Answer (score 3):

Since the exact operation you want here is a SQL style join, the `sqldf` package comes in handy:

```
library(sqldf)

sql <- "SELECT x.col1, COALESCE(y.col2, x.col2) AS col2
        FROM x LEFT JOIN y ON x.col1 = y.col1"
x <- sqldf(sql)
```

**Data:**

```
x <- data.frame(col1=c('a','c','b','d'), col2=c(11,34,13,25))
y <- data.frame(col1=c('a','b'), col2=c(3,5))
```